# Vite: how to fix "does not provide an export named 'default" when importing Ramda

Tags: reactjs, vite, ramda.js

I have a project that is running on vite and Ramda but I have a "does not provide an export named 'default'" error when using Ramda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same problem with Vite + React project. As per Ramda documentation: "ramda versions > 0.25 don't have a default export. So instead of `import R from 'ramda'`, one has to use `import * as R from 'ramda'` or `import { functionName } from 'ramda'`".

Using `import * as R from 'ramda'` fixed issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try toggling **curly braces** `{}` on and off. `export default something` and `import something from wherever`. Maybe this will help?